# SQLServer Transaction Isolation Analogy

Tags: sql-server

Does anyone have a good analogy of SQLServer transaction isolation levels? (SQL2005 upward)

Comment: Some developers are completely ignorant of their existence, I know they exist & have dabbled.  I need something to entice the team into the arena for a proper discussion.  Maybe even get the boss involved.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you have a problem that can only be solved by changing transaction levels? They're well documented in Books Online, but unless you have a practical application in mind then it's not clear what you need. And if by "analogy" you mean "simple explanation" then the Wikipedia article seems quite clear.

Comment: I've seen a few deadlocks on a project recently.  Looking at some code I'm not surprised.  I need to introduce the topic in such a way that folks don't just start nodding, thinking "that's your problem, not mine." - I believe anyone writing sql on the project should have some understanding of the locking implications of their code.

About.com also has a simple explanation:
http://databases.about.com/od/sqlserver/a/isolationmodels.htm

I thought a good analogy might fix it in our minds better.

Comment: I just came across [this blog post](http://www.littlekendra.com/2011/02/08/isoposter/) which you might find of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best analogy I've been able to use is Source Code control and building apps.  A check out is a lock and a build is a transaction.

I've not written this down before, so the following is just a brief summary of the concept I use.  Like any analogy, it will fall apart if you stretch it too far.

Read Committed - the code is checked out (locked) and you cannot build the code (transaction) until the code is checked in.

Read Uncommitted - you can see the code, but you do not know if it is the old version or the updated version.  A build may work or may not work depending on if all of the code has been checked in yet.

Repeatable Read - files cannot be checked out while a build is in progress, but files can be  added to the project if they do not affect the build.

Serializable - files cannot be checked out or added while the build is in progress; the entire project is in use/checked out (range lock).

Snapshot - the user works with the files labeled as a release, but does not see changes for the next release.